# MsgProc never receive WM_ messages?

Tags: visual-studio, programming-languages, 64-bit, c++

I had an program which worked fine and am trying to make some updates now.
But it seems no more to receive some windows message, like WM_LBUTTONDOWN or WM_SETCURSOR (WM_CREATE is called). I don't know what's the problem.

This is about a layered window created like that:

```
wc.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style=CS_CLASSDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc=MsgProc;
wc.cbClsExtra=0L;
wc.cbWndExtra=0L;
wc.hInstance=GetModuleHandle(NULL);
wc.hIcon=NULL;
wc.hbrBackground=NULL;
wc.lpszMenuName=NULL;
wc.lpszClassName="myapp";
wc.hCursor=hmain;

RegisterClassEx( &wc );

// Create the application's window
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TOPMOST, "myapp", "myapp", 
                          WS_POPUPWINDOW|WS_THICKFRAME|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 10, 10, desiredwidth, desiredheight,
                          GetDesktopWindow(), NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL );
```

I am developping under Visual Studio Express 2008 on Windows 7 x64 (I started this program on Win7 x86)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The window isn't visible. Add `WS_VISIBLE` to your styles, or call `ShowWindow()`.

Comment: My windows is visible but don't receive WM_SETCURSOR and some other messages.

Comment: paste your window proc code and message loop as well then. Make sure you're calling `DefWindowProc` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake ! I removed the following lines:

```
    while( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
```

Don't know how it could happen but really stupid !

Comment: Calling PeekMessage is terrible – you should call GetMessage! And be careful exactly how you form the while loop. I recommend you use the one quote in the MSDN documentation topic for GetMessage.